# Cannot update RecyclerView inside a Fragment

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have an activity that uses a ViewPager to contain 2 Fragments. Inside one of the fragments I have a recyclerView. Until now When I first run the app the view is show correctly. The fragment makes a request to a web service and loads the data into the fragment's recyclerview and all good. Now my problem is that I must filter the data loaded into the recycler view from the MainActivity by just passing an Integer number but the recyclerview is not updating.

This is my code:

how I set my viewPager in MainActivity:

```
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapterpager = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),context);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapterpager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        ActivitiesFragment activitiesFragment = new ActivitiesFragment(context);
        ArticlesFragment articlesFragment = new ArticlesFragment(context);
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();

        if (position==0) {
            fragment = activitiesFragment;
        }else if (position==1){
            fragment = articlesFragment;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        position = position+1;
        String tabTittle="Activities";
        if (position==2){
            tabTittle = "Articles";
        }
        return tabTittle;
    }
}
```

My ActivitiesFragment:

```
public class ActivitiesFragment extends Fragment implements ActivitiesResponse {

    private RecyclerView activityRecycler;
    private RequestMethods req;
    private String skillId="1";
    private String babyId="50";
    Context context;
    private ActivitiesRecyclerAdapter activitiesRecyclerAdapter;

    public ActivitiesFragment(Context context) {
        // Required empty public constructor
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activities, container, false);
        activityRecycler = v.findViewById(R.id.activities_recycler);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
        activityRecycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        req = new RequestMethods(context);
        req.getActivities(skillId,babyId,0);
        req.onActivityResponse(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void getActivities(List<Activity> list, int age) {

        List<Activity> activityList = new ArrayList<>();
        int listPos=0;
        if (age==0){
            activityList = list;
        }else{
        for (int x =0;x<list.size();x++){
            if (list.get(x).getAge()==age){
                activityList.add(listPos,list.get(x));
                listPos++;
            }
        }
        }
        activitiesRecyclerAdapter = new ActivitiesRecyclerAdapter(activityList, context, new OnItemActivityClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(List<Activity> list, int position) {
                Log.e("response_data","Click "+list.get(position).getName());
            }
        });

        activityRecycler.setAdapter(activitiesRecyclerAdapter);
    }
    public void requestActivities(int age){
        RequestMethods request = new RequestMethods(context);
        request.onActivityResponse(this);
        request.getActivities(skillId,babyId,age);
    }
}
```

I have tried updating my Recyclerview using a the Override method `getActivities(List<Activity> list, int age){}` but nothing have worked till now. I have been stuck for hours please help!

Comment: you should call `recyclerview.notifyDataSetChanged()` any time you make an update

Comment: @LiNKeR Where should I do that?

Comment: the point after new data has been fed to your recylerview(probably the moment you update whatever hashmap,array, or list that holds the data in its class). You should do it with a post runnable(so data is fed in when the recyclerview's UI is idle i.e. `recylerview.post(new runn...)` then inside that `recyclerview.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Consider using [`DiffUtil`](https://blog.mindorks.com/the-powerful-tool-diff-util-in-recyclerview-android-tutorial)